# Magento product stock alert cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I recently discovered my product stock alert e-mails aren't being sent. When I checked the cron_schedule table in my DB, I see the following:

[image: cronfail]

Which basically tells me there hasn't been any execution of this job since november 2014. Since this is a (fairly large) live site, I'd like to double check a few things. Would it be safe for me to change the following:

from config.xml in this path: app\code\core\Mage\ProductAlert\etc

```
<jobs>
   <catalog_product_alert>           
      <run>
     <model>productalert/observer::process</model>
  </run>
  </catalog_product_alert>
</jobs>
```

to

```
<jobs>
   <catalog_product_alert>
         <schedule>
     <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
         </schedule>            
     <run>
     <model>productalert/observer::process</model>
  </run>
  </catalog_product_alert>
```

Since there have been thousands of product stock alert subscribers since that date.. I'm not quite sure if it is safe to do so.

EDIT:  As for right now I'm starting to wonder if this is in fact the problem. I've checked the `product_alert_stock` table and it tells me the last e-mail was sent on june 7th, which is also not correct but maybe this particular cron catalog_product_alert is no longer used for this execution. Does anybody know wether this is true or not?

Answer (score 2):

Install the AOE Scheduler for Magento https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

It will show you if your cron setup is running properly and let you manually run cron jobs to test them. It is a very useful module for managing Magento cron tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't **ever** modify core files, create your own extension with its config.xml.
You could wipe data for this cron from `cron_schedule` just to be sure the thousand of them don't get executed in the catch up Magento might do.

Also make sure your cron.php is executed on a regular basis (every 5 minutes or so).

Comment: I know that (about modifying core files), but thanks anyway. As for right now I'm starting to wonder if this is in fact the problem. I've checked the `product_alert_stock` table and it tells me the last e-mail was sent on june 7th, which is also not correct but maybe this particular cron catalog_product_alert is no longer used for this execution.

Comment: I forgot to ask, does any other cron run on a regular basis? By that I mean are you sure your crons are actually running (I'm sure `cron.php` is because it fills your `cron_schedule`).

Answer (score 1):

The cronjob `catalog_product_alert` is used to process the alert emails. For further details you can take a look at the module `Mage_ProductAlert` itself.

The cron time will be set in backend: `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Alerts` There is no need to add a `cron_expr` node to the config.xml

**In general**

You should monitor the cron_schedule table if the cronjob gets schedules:

```
select * from cron_schedule where job_code='catalog_product_alert'\G
```

You should take a look if the product is really set back to stock

```
select * from cataloginventory_stock_status where product_id=[??]
```

You should monitor the stock alert table for the test customer

```
select * from product_alert_stock where product_id=[??];
```

You can also write a little helper script to trigger the stock alert:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$foobar = new Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer;
$foobar->process();

echo "OK";
```

This should echo you potential issues. If the send_date get added to the table but you didn't receive an email, check spam folder and try with a different email address.